# Green's theorem using polar coordinates and substitution

Tags: greens-theorem

[image: Question]

Hi, I'm having doubts to how I'm supposed to draw the graph of the triangle, 
is it just $y=x\tan(\alpha)$ and $y= -x\tan(\alpha)$ and $x=1$ and sketch the region?.

Also for the integral I calculated it to be

> $\frac{1}{2}  \left[\tan(\alpha) + \frac{\tan^3(\alpha)}{3 }\right]. $

Is the integral calculation correct?

Comment: Yes, this looks fine.

Comment: I tried graphing y=xtan(alpha) on a graphing software and it's just dots on the graph, are you sure it's the right graph

Comment: I think so - for example, if $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{4}$, then R is the region bounded above by $y=x$, below by $y=-x$, and on the right by $x=1$.  Similarly, $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{3}$ gives the region bounded above by $y=\sqrt{3}x$, bounded below by $y=-\sqrt{3}x$, and on the right by $x=1$.